# how to properly add newline in xml through php?

Tags: php, xml, newline

i have a php code that will add child in xml, my question is how to write that child in new line

```
$string = simplexml_load_file($config['string']);

$string->addChild('name', $nick);
```

i would like to add the child in new line and it doesnt matter if it start with new line or end with it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggest you go read http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php it explains adding a child in etc, basicaly you need to add an element (or add the child to the existing element) and then re-save your xml out.

Comment: thanks, but it doesnt answer my question of adding the child in new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a display problem. XML itself couldn't care less if your document looks like

```
<root>
    <nick>foo</nick>
    <nick>bar</nick>
</root>
```

or

```
<root><nick>foo</nick><nick>bar</nick></root>
```

Both are perfectly valid XML and will parse into the same DOM tree. Whitespace in tag interstitials is irrelevant.

Comment: i know it doesnt matter, i only like it to look arranged that's all, if there's no way to add it in a newline then it's fine, but i rather if it did.
thanks

Comment: DOM itself doesn't, because "beautification" is not what DOM is about. You can use an html beautifier after you do a `->saveXML()` call.